# Different authors, same name and same year of publication in natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, date

In my thesis, I cite two different authors who have the same name, and their work were published the same year. This appears in my bibliography as follows:

- Levinson, Peter. 2016a. ...
- Levinson, Simon. 2016b. ...

I would like to remove the 'a' and 'b' following the dates (2016), as they suggest that both publications were written by the same author.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Remark: It's not the `natbib` citation management, but the bibliography style, that determines how the entries are formatted. Hence, please tell us which bibliography style you employ. Please also edit your posting to show the complete entries for Peter Levinson 2016 and for Simon Levinson 2016.

Comment: An additional question: does you document generate numeric-style or authoryear-style citation call-outs?

Comment: Incidentally, which alternative to using extended year labels, such as "2016a" and "2016b", do you have in mind? Since the bibliography contains two publications that were authored by Levinson and published in 2016, how would you distinguish unambiguously between call-outs to the two publications? Would you maybe want to make the authors' first initials -- P and S, respectively -- part of the citation call-outs?